# Find the number of ways to move along the grid from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ such that one is always in the region $x \geq y$.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, catalan-numbers

Here is the Question :-

Find the number of ways to move along the grid from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ such that one is always in the region $x \geq y$.

First of all , I kind of couldn't understand the part which meant the region $x \geq y$ , and the answer is given as the nth Catalan number $C_n$ . But I couldn't understand why and how .

Any hints or explanations to this Question will be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: The region $x \ge y$ is literally that -- the set of points where $x \ge y$, including e.g. $(3,1), (3,3)$ but excluding e.g. $(1,2)$.  Also, did you make the minimal attempt of checking [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics)?

Comment: Oh okay , I got the meaning of  $x \geq y$ , and yes , I did check wikipedia as well , but I still couldn't understand why it is $C_n$ , or does that mean the question is same as asking no. of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ such that it does not crosses a diagonal?

Comment: The wikipedia article listed six proofs, of which the 2nd and 3rd directly address your grid problem, and the 5th and 6th directly address Dyck words which are in obvious 1-to-1 correspondence to your paths.